# How to calculate hash value of hard disk in java?(ShA-256 or MD5 implementation)

Tags: java

```
byte[] buffer= new byte[8192];
int count;
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
while ((count = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    digest.update(buffer, 0, count);
}
bis.close();
byte[] hash = digest.digest();
System.out.println(new BASE64Encoder().encode(hash));
```

this is my cod to calculate hash of file

Comment: Hello and welcome. What's your question?

Comment: And what is the problem with this implementation?

Comment: It only calculates hash value of one file

Answer (score 1):

This worked, but it will take a while for a large disk.  I updated the buffer size.  You can substitute your own logical file letter.

```
File file = new File("\\\\.\\f:");
byte[] buffer= new byte[1<<24];
int count;
long totalCount = 0;
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
while ((count = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    digest.update(buffer, 0, count);
    totalCount += count;
    System.out.printf("%,d%n", totalCount);
}
bis.close();
byte[] hash = digest.digest();
System.out.println(digest);
```